# Vera++ not working with Visual Lint in Visual Studio 2008 (cannot open profile)

Tags: visual-studio-2008, code-analysis, fatal-error, vera++

Visual Studio 2008 in Windowx Xp SP3

I have [Vera++](https://bitbucket.org/verateam/vera/wiki/Home) installed, as well as [CppCheck](http://cppcheck.sourceforge.net/), and I'm trying to use them using the [Visual Lint](http://www.riverblade.co.uk/products/visual_lint/index.html) toolbar.

If I select CppCheck and then start the background analysis, it works fine and the results show what I would expect.

However, if I select Vera++ and run the analysis I get a Fatal Error (on all files) saying:

> Issue error: (Fatal Error -- cannot open profile description for
>   profile default)

The configuration option I have is basically the path to the Vera installation which is correct.

Any ideas on what I need to do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was due to the Vera++ download being incomplete.

I had to download the extra files separately (from the same website) and add them to the Vera installation.

The Vera site isn't too clear about installation instructions!

All working now though.

Comment: Which files did you have to separately download?

Answer (score 1):

If I remember correctly that error message is one you will get if Vera++ cannot locate the default profile folder using the VERA_ROOT environment variable.

If the var isn’t set, Visual Lint will try to define it (for the duration of the process) when it starts, but it is possible that there are some conditions under which this does not happen. We can certainly look into this, of course.

Can you tell me which version of Visual Lint you are running?

Comment: set VERA_ROOT=C:\Program Files (x86)\vera++\lib\vera++